# Java not writing to zip file

Tags: java, zip

I have the following java method which I'm trying to use to create a zip file, which has an existing file written into it (the zip file has the same name, just with the .log extension replaced with .zip) .  The zip file is created successfully, however the file is not inside it when it completes.

Here is my code:

```
private static void zipFile(File fileToZip) {

    final int bufferSize = 2048;
    File zipFile = new File(fileToZip.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll(".log", ".zip"));

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile.getAbsolutePath());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
            BufferedInputStream origin = new BufferedInputStream(fis, bufferSize)) {

        ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getAbsolutePath());
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
        int count;
        while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
            LOGGER.info("WRITING!!!");
            zos.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error: ", e);
    }

}
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Works for me, though using the absolute pathname is a strange choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getAbsolutePath());
```

to

```
ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName());
```